# Convert date formate in .xls file, while exporting the file using c#

Tags: c#

I am exporting data to .xls file(Excel doc) by using C#.net. 
here I have a one **date** field. Now i want to change the date format. Diff-Diff date formats in the Excel document.

```
protected void ExportToExcel(DataSet ds, string FilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter sw;
            StringBuilder strFileContents = new StringBuilder();
            strFileContents.Append("ID" + "\t" + "ItemName" + "\t" + "Initiated By" + "\t" + "Date of Initiation" + "\t" + "Date of Expiry" + "\t" + "Item Price" + "\t" + "Name" + "\t" + "Phone" + "\t" + "Company" + "\t" + "Address");
            strFileContents.Append("\n");
            if (ds != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    strFileContents.Append(row["ID"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["ItemName"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["UserName"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["DealInitiatedOn"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["DealExpiryDate"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["ItemPrice"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["FullName"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["Phone"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["Company"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append(row["Address"] + "\t");
                    strFileContents.Append("\n");
                }
            }
            sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(FilePath);
            sw.Write(ISpace.CommLive.UI.User.CommonFunctions.StripHTMLTags(strFileContents.ToString()));
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Thanks,
Jagadi

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method allows you to specify formatting parameters.

```
string myFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" // <= your format goes here
strFileContents.Append(((DateTime)row["DealExpiryDate"]).ToString(myFormat) + "\t");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: But by using ur code, I am getting error like. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following

```
string format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
strFileContents.Append((DateTime.Parse(row["DealExpiryDate"])).ToString(format) + "\t");
```

Instead of Parse function, DateTime.TryParse can also be used, if necessary.

**Alternative approach:**

```
string format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
DateTime? expDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("DealExpiryDate");
if(expDate.HasValue)
{
    strFileContents.Append(expDate.Value.ToString(format) + "\t");
}
```